# C#: ASCII to Hex: Output hex as "01" instead of "1"

Tags: c#, hex, ascii, space

I am in the process of writing an ASCII to Hex conversion program. When I put spaces into the program it outputs them as "1"; I would prefer that it output as "01".

How would I go about forcing the "0" to display?

part of the static Dictionary used in the code:

```
static Dictionary<char, int> cyper = new Dictionary<char, int>
{
{' ', 01},
};
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have it as a string? If so - might I suggest using the `ASCIIEncoding` class?

Comment: If you looked at my answer to your previous question, you'd see how to do it... and a better way than using a dictionary (IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

You should print values out using *appropriate format* (`"x2"`) in your case:

```
  Console.WriteLine(cyper[' '].ToString("x2")); // <- will print "01"
```

I've assumed that you want *hexadecimal* representation, i.e. `15` will be `"0f"`